# Как сделать, чтобы каждый элемент ListView отображался в формате 3 строки?

Tags: android

у меня есть ListView с атрибутом textMultiLine. Как сделать, чтобы на экране отображались только первые 3 строчки каждого элемента в списке? (тексты длинные, в дальнейшем буду делать, чтобы при нажатии на каждый элемент будет открываться Activity, отображающее текст полностью).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задать у `TextView`

```
android:lines="3"
```

или

```
android:maxLines="3"
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но я немного не поняла как это задать у компонента ListView?

Comment: Нужно задать эти атрибуты не у ListView, а у элемента списка, чем с вероятностью 99% является TextView

Comment: у меня изначальной пустой listView, а текстовые сообщения будут добавляться пользователем через EditText.. Я наверно очень туплю, но не понимаю где указать атрибут maxlines при такой раскладке (если указываю полю ввода - не работает)